# Django Serializer with Many To Many fileld returns empty list, How to fix it?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have two models `Product` and `Lessons`. I join them in one Product serializer. But I get empty list in `lesson` fileld. This is what I am getting now:

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Python",
        "owner": 1,
        "lessons": [] # here should be lessons
    },
```

my modelds.py

```
class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Lesson(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    video_link = models.URLField()
    duration = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name='lessons')
```

My serializers.py

```
class LessonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        
        model = Lesson
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'video_link', 'duration')

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    lessons = LessonSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:

        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'owner', 'lessons']
```

And my view.py

```
class LessonListView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    def get_queryset(self):
                lesson_view = Product.objects.all()
        return products_view
```

I can see many topics in the internet about that but I it is not working for me at all.
How can I resolve it and get my data that I have for `lessons` field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite the Product serializer as below:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:

    model = Product
    fields = ['id', 'name', 'owner', 'lessons']

def to_representation(self, instance):
    data = super(ProductSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
    data["lessons"] = LessonSerializer(Lesson.objects.filter(products__in=[instance.id]), many=True).data
    
    return data
```

Your views:

```
class LessonListView(ListAPIView):
serializer_class = ProductSerializer
permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]

def get_queryset(self):
    return Product.objects.all()
```